# bash script options parser fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a `bashscript.sh` that I `$ chmod +x bashscript.sh` and move it to `$ mv bashscript.sh ~/.local/bin/` in order for it to be executable like a system command.

I'd like to be able to invoke it with

```
bashscript [<-w|-working|--working>[=|:]] <y|yes|n|no>
```

And return usage/help/error (call it whatever we want) if the call isn't respected.

To do so, I wrote this parsing part:

```
usage(){
  echo "you're wrong."
  exit 1
}
[[ $# -lt 1 ]] && usage
options=$(getopt -o y,n,h,w: -l yes,no,help,working: -- "$@")
set -- $options
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help|*) usage
      shift;;
    y|yes)
      #do something
      shift;;
    n|no)
      #..
      shift;;
    -w|-working|--working)
      shift;;
    --) #this is just syntax
      shift
      break;;
  esac
done
```

But when I test it doesn't work as intended*, would you know why/have a sample that handles my option possibilites?

*edit : I always trigger the usage display

edit 2 : removed the spaces around the "=" of options as @costaparas3 pointed out, thank you, still stuck to usage() though

Comment: What do behavior do you observe?

Comment: it always brings me back to usage output. example : $ bashscript -w n

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Move the case `-h|--help|*)` to the end because it contains `*`, and the shell will use the first matching case.

Comment: @bodo has hit the main point ... first `case` statement includes `*` => matches everything; if removing the `*` doesn't address the issue ... please provide an example of how you're invoking your script so we can see what's being passed in on the command line

Answer (score 2):

Here are the issues I found:

1. Exit if there are no arguments
2. Set the options with `options=$(...` (no spaces)
3. `-h|--help|*)` matches everything so you have an infinite loop.  You don't need to match on * as getopt will reuturn non-zero if it finds an invalid argument, and the match on -- is what usually terminates the loop.
4. getopt returns non-zero for invalid arguments so exit 1 then
5. Use -n|--no to specify short and long options
6. --working requires an argument but you only shift 1.
7. -working is not valid (with getopt).  Use either -w or --working.

Here is corrected version:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
  echo "you're wrong."
  exit $1
}

[ $# -lt 1 ] && usage

options=$(getopt -o y,n,h,w: -l yes,no,help,working: -- "$@")
[ $? -ne 0 ] && usage 1

# default values
yes=
working=

set -- $options
while :
do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      usage
      ;;
    -y|--yes)
      yes=1
      shift
      ;;
    -n|--no)
      yes=0 # or no=1
      shift
      ;;
    -w|--working)
      working=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    --)
      break
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: thank you, might set your answer as solving the issue. Why don't you set a value after your exit please? Why do I have to shift 2 times for option w that requires an argument ? (what happens theoretically when I bashscript -w y ?) Also I would like to display usage even as soon as the call is wrong, even if the guy didn't ask for -h|--help

Comment: @dockerwonderer You can run the script like `bash -x ./scriptname -w foo` to see what happens with option arguments.

Comment: @dockerwonderer you mean exit with a non-zero status?  usage would be a normal case, but I added a exit 1 for when getopt finds invalid syntax.  -w y means $1 is "-w" and $2 is "y".  You usually assign things to variables.  `working=$2; shift 2`. Replace the exit with a usage(1) and `exit $1` in usage for your last requirement.  I updated answer with that change.

Comment: thank you I learned a lot. Two last questions though : what if I only want to do something for case yes/no ? (you also do something in case -w in your script). And would it exist a way to include both 1-dash-full-"working"/1-dash-full-"help" as well as no-dash-short-"y/n"/no-dash-long-"yes/no" ?

Comment: Well, all it does right now it setting variable.  After you processed all the arguments you decide what to do with those `if [ "$yes" = 0 ] then ...`.  In my version of getopt you can get the -long-option feature with `getopt -a`.  If you also argument to process arguments (without -, --) then you have to iterate through whatever it left after you process the options.  Maybe change to `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` and the -- would just do a shift, and let the loop decide when done.  Then for each case add -n|--no|n.  Arguments are positional, usually required, so it's would be a non-standard syntax.